# How to retrieve distinct meta value from post meta excluding trashed posts

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I'm trying to display distinct suburbs with the their count and a checkbox with each of them.
Current code is as below:

```
  $metakey = 'wpcf-suburb';

  $suburbs = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s ORDER BY meta_value ASC", $metakey) );

 if ($suburbs) {

echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"all\" name=\"subchkall\" class=\"fcbox subchkall\">Select All<br/>";

foreach ($suburbs as $suburb) {

$subcount = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s AND meta_value = %s", $metakey, $suburb) );

  echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"" . $suburb . "\" name=\"arSuburb[]\" class=\"fcbox subchkbox\">" . $suburb . ' (' . $subcount . ')<br/>';

}

}
```

Output looks like - [] Officer (4)

This will show count of all meta field with value 'Officer' including trashed or draft posts.

How can i display the count of meta fields of all posts with publish status only.? Is it possible with get_col() and get_var() functions?

Please help.. Thanking you..

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
   'meta_key' => 'wpcf-suburb',
   'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
   'order' => 'ASC',
   'meta_query' => array(
       array(
           'key' => 'wpcf-suburb',

       )
   )
 );
 $query = new WP_Query($args);
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($query);
 echo "</pre>";
```

try this

**REFER HERE [WP QUERY](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)**

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for the response. But WHERE post_status = 'publish' is not working.. post_status is stored in 'posts' table but my above query is for 'postmeta' table data

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference go there and look for functions under `Custom Fields (postmeta)`

Comment: Thank you., i'm trying to get the value of a meta key from all posts.. not able to find a function for that. i will try to use join.